# Liquibase importing sql files for mysql fails on multiple statements

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I'm trying to start using Liquibase for a project that already has multiple SQL changelog files (that were previously maintained by hand). Using an advise from somewhere on stackoverflow I added a

```
<includeAll path="db/initial"/>
```

directive to my initial change log file, but it was failing with a not very useful

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

message. Playing around I figured out that the problem is with multiple sql statements in the file. As long as I supplied a file with only one statement it worked.

So how do I tell Liquibase to execute multiple statements from an sql file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit more searching to figure out that the problem is not with Liquibase but with MySql driver that by default refuses to execute multiple statements.

The key bit was to add allowMultiQueries=true to my connection string:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_project?allowMultiQueries=true
```

Comment: Note for future readers -- although this does work, you can avoid changing the JDBC settings by making use of liquibase's "splitStatements" attribute, as put by @mark-oconnor in his answer. To my case that was a vastly more interesting solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would expected that you'd be using a [sql_file](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html) refactoring to import a SQL file. It supports a "splitStatements" attribute that would solve your issue without the need to make changes to your JDBC settings.

The [include](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html) statement is normally used to import liquibase changelogs....  Have you adapted your files to be  [formatted SQL changelogs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html)? It would be well worth trying this out, I've included an example file:

## Example

### scottTiger.sql

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset mark:1
CREATE TABLE BONUS (ENAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, JOB VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, SAL DECIMAL(7, 2), COMM DECIMAL(7, 2));
ALTER TABLE BONUS ADD CONSTRAINT BONUS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ENAME, JOB);
--rollback DROP TABLE BONUS;

--changeset mark:2
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (DEPTNO INT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(14), LOCATION VARCHAR(13), CONSTRAINT DEPT_PK PRIMARY KEY (DEPTNO));
--rollback DROP TABLE DEPARTMENT;


--changeset mark:3
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMPNO INT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(10), JOB VARCHAR(9), BOSS INT, HIREDATE VARCHAR(12), SALARY DECIMAL(7, 2), COMM DECIMAL(7, 2), DEPTNO INT, CONSTRAINT EMP_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO));
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT BOSS_FK FOREIGN KEY (BOSS) REFERENCES PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE (EMPNO) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES PUBLIC.DEPARTMENT (DEPTNO) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
--rollback DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE;


--changeset mark:4
CREATE TABLE PROJECT (PROJECTNO INT NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100), START_DATE VARCHAR(12), END_DATE VARCHAR(12), CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PK PRIMARY KEY (PROJECTNO));
--rollback DROP TABLE PROJECT;

--changeset mark:5
CREATE TABLE ROLE (ROLE_ID INT NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100), CONSTRAINT ROLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROLE_ID));
--rollback DROP TABLE ROLE;


--changeset mark:6
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_PARTICIPATION (PROJECTNO INT NOT NULL, EMPNO INT NOT NULL, START_DATE VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, END_DATE VARCHAR(12), ROLE_ID INT);
ALTER TABLE PROJECT_PARTICIPATION ADD CONSTRAINT PARTICIPATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PROJECTNO, EMPNO, START_DATE);
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.PROJECT_PARTICIPATION ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK FOREIGN KEY (EMPNO) REFERENCES PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE (EMPNO) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.PROJECT_PARTICIPATION ADD CONSTRAINT PROJECT_FK FOREIGN KEY (PROJECTNO) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PROJECT (PROJECTNO) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.PROJECT_PARTICIPATION ADD CONSTRAINT ROLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (ROLE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ROLE (ROLE_ID) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
--rollback DROP TABLE PROJECT_PARTICIPATION;

--changeset mark:7
CREATE TABLE SALARYGRADE (GRADE INT NOT NULL, LOSAL INT NOT NULL, HISAL INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT SALGRADE_PK PRIMARY KEY (GRADE));
--rollback DROP TABLE SALARYGRADE;
```

Note:

- One thing I love about liquibase is its support for rollbacks.

Comment: I used includeAll so that I don't need to list each sql file individually. I don't care too much about rollbacks or formatting the changelogs as these are the pre-liquibase changelogs that are already applied to all prod servers, I need them mostly for rolling out dev/test servers (previously I was doing that manually with mysql command line).

Comment: the --liquibase formatted sql at the top of the file is necessary.  I was missing it and that was causing me not to be able to have multiple sql statemets in a sql file